# Calculating the Ring of Invariant Polynomials for the Action of a Compact Simple Lie Group

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, invariant-theory

Let $G$ be a compact connected simple Lie group and let $V$ be a real $G$-representation.  How does one go about computing the ring of $G$-invariant (polynomial?) functions $V \to \mathbb{R}$?

I've been told that this ring is always the coordinate ring of some algebraic variety, which sounds important.

I would really appreciate any references that address this, preferably a textbook that contains lots of down-to-earth examples.  I should underscore that I'm a differential geometer whose interest is in concrete computations, not an algebraist seeking the most general powerful theorems possible.

Comment: In the case of real numbers, this might be quite hard. Can you give an idea of the dimensions you are dealing with? What exactly does it mean for you to compute this ring, are you interested in a set of generators? The best book I know on the topic of [Computational Invariant Theory](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783642077968) is, well, that one - but I am not sure how good of a fit this is, in fact I am afraid it will be too algebraic for your taste.

Comment: For me, $G$ is a product of compact simple Lie groups, with each factor having rank $\leq 3$.  The vector space $V$ is of relatively low dimension (let's say $\leq 30$).  And yes, I'd be primarily interested in a set of generators.

Comment: Frankly, that sounds very tough to me. I hope someone else has something more constructive for you, but I'm not sure this is computationally feasible with what we know right now.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain: OK, let's make things much simpler.  Let's say $G$ is a compact simple (not semi-simple) Lie group of rank $\leq 3$ and that $V$ is a real $G$-representation.  Surely then we can say something, no?

Comment: I honestly do not know, this might or might not stand a chance of being computable. Let me remark that this definitely sounds like a research level question to me: I seriously doubt that you will find a straightforward description, let alone formula in any textbook. I find the question very interesting but currently have no time to pursue it =(.